# how to look for space in preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I have this code in preg_match

```
 if (preg_match("/(for+\([\w\-]+\;[\w\-]+\;[\w\-]+\){)/",$email))
   {
   $message = "Valid input";
   }
else
   $message ="Invalid Input";
```

if the user will input `for(aw;aw;aw){`

if will output Valid input

but if the user will put a space  like `for (awd ; awd; awd) {` 
it will output invalid input..

my problem is how can i bypass space or remove space without using explode to my string..

need help..

Comment: Just so you know, your regular expression also matches the string `forrrr(awwww;aw;aw){`.  Not sure if this is intentional.

Answer (score 0):

You can match a space like any other character. So for example, you can just add spaces where needed, like below:

```
if (preg_match("/(for+ *\([\w\-]+ *\; *[\w\-]+ *\; *[\w\-]+\) *{)/",$email))
```

However, `for+` matches 1 or more literal `r`'s so would also match positively on `forrrr`, so just using `for` might be more appropriate there.